# Problem Installing windows over ubuntu -- grub install error

Tags: grub2, windows, xubuntu, asus, tablet

I recently installed Ubuntu on my Asus T100TAF. Alas, I rushed into it, not knowing no one had a fix for the sound yet. I'm trying to get back to windows by following this guide: http://onetransistor.blogspot.com/2014/09/make-bootable-windows-usb-from-ubuntu.html

When I get to step 3, which is entering this into the terminal:

```
sudo grub-install --target=i386-pc --boot-directory="/media/<username>/<drive_label>/boot" /dev/sdX
```

I get this error:

```
grub-install: error: /usr/lib/grub/i386-pc/modinfo.sh doesn't exist. Please specify --target or --directory.
```

Could anyone tell me what's gone wrong, and help me complete this step?

Comment: Why not just follow http://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubuntu

Comment: @DnrDevil , I tried that, but the WinUSB link seems to be broken.

Comment: On 14 you have to install the .deb first

Comment: Welcome to AU ! You want to make a Win bootable USB drive, rather than a dual boot. Not sure you are "on-topic" here.... Either way and although you might eventually get _some_ help here, yr best bet is to try the "General Help" section of the Ubuntu Forum at  http://ubuntuforums.org. --- In case making a dual boot instead crosses yr mind, you should know that it is more usual to install a Linux Ubuntu alongside an existing M$Win, rather than the opposite.  Make sure to state you're dealing with BIOS-MBR rather than GPT - UEFI as the two config's protocols are different from one another. ;-)

Comment: @chhihe , I am not trying to dual-boot ubuntu with windows. I am trying to replace ubuntu with windows.

Comment: @Cbhihe he is asking how to do this from ubuntu its on topic.

Comment: @DnrDevil , The interface will not open and the commands aren't doing anything. I am running Ubuntu 15.10 with Xubuntu

Answer (score 2):

I have reasons to believe that your Ubuntu installation is in UEFI mode. Are you sure you want to make a MBR bootable USB drive of Windows and install Windows in non-UEFI mode?

Anyway, for your situation, the answer is right on the page with the tutorial:

> **'modinfo.sh' doesn't exist**
>
> `grub-install: error: /usr/lib/grub/i386-pc/modinfo.sh doesn't exist. Please specify --target or --directory.`
>
> Install the grub-pc-bin package with sudo apt-get install grub-pc-bin and run the grub-install command again.

But if you want to **make an UEFI bootable USB** just copy Windows files from mounted image to a FAT32 formatted USB drive.

Answer (score 0):

I would use WinUsb to accomplish this.

You first you need the .deb for 14.04  [here](https://launchpad.net/~colingille/+archive/ubuntu/freshlight/+files/winusb_1.0.11%2Bsaucy1_i386.deb)(64bit) or 32bit [here](https://launchpad.net/~colingille/+archive/ubuntu/freshlight/+files/winusb_1.0.11%2Bsaucy1_i386.deb)

Then follow the install guide for winusb [here](https://launchpad.net/~colingille/+archive/ubuntu/freshlight/+files/winusb_1.0.11%2Bsaucy1_i386.deb)

Then follow [how to install bootable windows on ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubuntu)

Comment: installed winusb and it shows up in my applications, but it will not open and the commands for the terminal do not work. I am running Ubuntu 15.10 with Xubuntu